# Autoencoders for Dimensionality Reduction of Sensor Data with many missing Values

Tags: missing-data, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

The setting I am considering is the following:

In varying time-intervals we receive numerical data from a range of approx. 200 sensors (of unknown nature), which hopefully allow us to predict the internal state of our system.
The readouts themselves are unreliable, in the usual case, I will only get a couple of readouts per day (I am pooling all sensory input on the level of a day) while not receiving any data from the other sensors.

I would like to learn a lower-dimensional representation of my input data, which, in it's raw form, would be a 200-dimensional vector with many missing values.

Would approaching the problem of dimensionality reduction with an autoencoder make sense in such a setting? Especially since the cost-function might be heavily driven by the imputed input values.

What kind of imputation strategy would you follow for the missing data?